# Is this a valid proof of the triangle inequality in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given the following definition of norm in $\mathbb R$

$$|x|=\left\{\begin{aligned} x & \text { , } x \geq 0 \\-x & \text { , } x<0 \end{aligned}\right.$$

I will like to proof $a+b \leq|a|+|b|$. This is actually a made up problem by myself, so it might not make much sense.

This is how I start. Let $a$ and $b$ to real numbers, then pr. definition of $|x|$ I have $|a| \ge a$ and $|b|\ge b$, so the sum $|a|+|b|$ must be bigger than $a+b$. Conclusion: is $|a+b| \leq|a|+|b|$.

Does this make since?

Kind regards

Comment: Yes this does prove the triangle inequality for the absolute value norm in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, All you have proved is that $a+b\le|a|+|b|$ which fact is trivial when $a+b<0$. What if $a+b<0$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Havn't you made a typing mistake? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a|\geq a$ and $|b|\geq b$,
Adding up the two inequality gives $$|a|+|b|\geq a+b$$
Similarly, by $|a|\geq -a$ and $|b|\geq -b$,
Therefore $$|a|+|b|\geq -(a+b)$$
Since $|a+b|=a+b$ or $-(a+b)$, the result follows.

Comment: This is also what I have done. So why is mine wrong?

Comment: The inequality $a+b<|a|+|b|$ is weaker than the triangle inequality $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$ in the sense that when $a+b$ is negative, the inequality is trivial.

Comment: I think get it now. You look at two instances: $a+b \ge 0$ and $a+b < 0$? But which one is which in your answer.

Comment: The first one is for $a+b\geq 0$ and the second one is for $a+b<0$.